# Label Colours on an @IBDesignable View appearing different of different devices

Tags: swift, ibdesignable

I have an @IBDesignable custom view.  It contain an UIView with two subclassed UILabels.  The custom subclass of UILabel is setting it's font.

What I'm trying to achieve is by changing by making the background colour of the view an inspectable property that the text colour change appropriately to be legible.

My code is below. `Custom.Colour.<name>` is just an enum of defined colours.

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomMiniView: UIView, NibLoadable {

public var view:UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var colourView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var headingLabel: CustomUILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var amountLabel: CustomUILabel!

@IBInspectable var blockColor:UIColor! {
    didSet {

        self.colourView.backgroundColor = blockColor

        switch blockColor {

        case Custom.Colour.darkBlue:
            headingLabel.textColor = .white
            amountLabel.textColor = .white

        case Custom.Colour.blue:
            headingLabel.textColor = .white
            amountLabel.textColor = .white

        case Custom.Colour.lightBlue:
            headingLabel.textColor = Custom.Colour.grey
            amountLabel.textColor = Custom.Colour.blue

        case Custom.Colour.green:
            headingLabel.textColor = .white
            amountLabel.textColor = .white

        case Custom.Colour.lightGreen:
            headingLabel.textColor = Custom.Colour.grey
            amountLabel.textColor = Custom.Colour.blue

        case Custom.Colour.yellow:
            headingLabel.textColor = Custom.Colour.grey
            amountLabel.textColor = Custom.Colour.grey

        default : printError("We have not handled text colours for a background of this colour. = \(blockColor.hexString)")
        }
    }
}

public override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.setupFromNib()
    self.commonInit()
}

public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.setupFromNib()
    self.commonInit()

}

func commonInit() {
    self.backgroundColor = .clear
}

}
```

This was working for me fine, however I was then getting report that the text was showing up as white everywhere and got sent a screen shot which confused me.  When I ran this in a simulator and a different device I was able to see this not working.  Here are two screen shots of what is happening on my iPad and what I expect to happen and a screen shot of what is happening on some other devices and the simulator.

This is what is happening on my device and the expected result.
[image: Correct and expected result.]

This is whats happening on other devices and the incorrect result.
[image]

Is there a reason this would appeared different of different devices?  I'm at a loss to the cause or how to fix this.

Comment: Try rawvalue to switch on your enum

Comment: Besides a `printError`, what should the `textColor` be when hitting the `default` condition?

Comment: @dfd  the text is set to white on the customView .xib  Interestingly it seemed the default case is getting called and logging "We have not handled text colours for a background of this colour. = #2F8DB3"  but that hex value is what I'm trying above and should match the case for .darkBlue

Comment: @dfd I dont have a raw value of the UIColor returned by enum but I've changed the switch to check the .hexString property (which I cribbed somwhere of SO) which has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments above I've found a fix.

Rather than doing a switch on the colour I've done a switch on the .hexString of the colour which has worked.

```
    switch blockColor.hexString {

    case Custom.Colour.darkBlue.hexString :
```

for the record hexString is an extension to UIColor

```
    var hexString: String {
    let colorRef = cgColor.components
    let r = colorRef?[0] ?? 0
    let g = colorRef?[1] ?? 0
    let b = ((colorRef?.count ?? 0) > 2 ? colorRef?[2] : g) ?? 0
    let a = cgColor.alpha

    var color = String(
        format: "#%02lX%02lX%02lX",
        lroundf(Float(r * 255)),
        lroundf(Float(g * 255)),
        lroundf(Float(b * 255))
    )

    if a < 1 {
        color += String(format: "%02lX", lroundf(Float(a)))
    }

    return color
}
```

I'm still not sure why switching on hexString worked and the UIColor in the enum did not work consistently but thanks to comments about that helped me find a solution to fix it myself.  Question for another time is why switching on UIColor would be unreliable but now back to work.